# Problema buscando en una lista

Tags: python, lista, comparaciones

Buenas tardes soy nuevo en python y estoy creado un programa para hacer una lista de precios en base a un xml.

lo que busco lograr es que se guarden solo los productos que no estén en la lista de desactivados para seguir con el proceso de crear dicha lista, mi código es el siguiente.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import settings
from utiles import quit_desactivate as quit_desactivate

PRODUCTS = []
tree = ET.parse('prices_list.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for neighbor in root.findall('PRODUCT'):
    PRODUCT_NUMBER = neighbor.find('PRODUCT_NUMBER').text.split('-')
    PRICE = neighbor.find('PRICE').text
    DESACTIVATE=quit_desactivate(PRODUCT_NUMBER[0])
    if DESACTIVATE == False:
     PRODUCTS.append((PRODUCT_NUMBER[0],PRICE))
```

esta es la funcion quit_desactivate()

```
import settings

def quit_desactivate(product):
   
   agrega = True
   for  desactivado in settings.DEACTIVATED:
       if product==desactivado:
           agrega=False
       else:
         agrega=True
      
   print('id '+product+' resultado:'+str(agrega)) //aqui lo imprimi para validar que lo haga
   return agrega
```

la lista donde están los desactivados es la sig.

```
DEACTIVATED = ['MO6122','MO9489','MO9086','MO9085','MO9261','MO9260','MO9386','MO9155','MO8906','S55000']
```

todo el código lo hace bien, hasta que hace la comparación ya que lo intente validar con el print pero siguen saliendo los que en teoría no deberían de aparecer, como que solo valida el ultimo de la lista.

```
ejemplo de lo que imprime
id MO9155 resultado:True  
id S47101 resultado:True
id S54500 resultado:True
id S55000 resultado:False
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
DEACTIVATED = ['MO6122','MO9489','MO9086','MO9085','MO9261','MO9260','MO9386','MO9155','MO8906','S55000']

def quit_desactivate(product):
   return (product in DEACTIVATED)
   # si quieres que retorn False si esta! solo niegas
   # return (not product in DEACTIVATED)
```

esto retornara **True** or **False**

ahora para validar solo seria hacer

```
# normal
if not quit_desactivate(PRODUCT_NUMBER[0]):
   PRODUCTS.append((PRODUCT_NUMBER[0],PRICE))

# si niegas
if quit_desactivate(PRODUCT_NUMBER[0]):
   PRODUCTS.append((PRODUCT_NUMBER[0],PRICE))
```

si quieres usar un for:

```
def quit_desactivate(product):
   for x in DEACTIVATED:
      if x == product:
         return True
   return False
```

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvió perfectamente

Answer (score 1):

Te falta salirte del `for` en caso de que lo quieras desactivar.

Al recorrer toda la lista y no salir del `for`, el `agregar` que vale es la última comparación.

```
for desactivado in settings.DEACTIVATED:
    if product==desactivado:
        agrega=False
        break
```

Una forma más idiomatica sería así

```
if product in settings.DEACTIVATED:
    agrega=False
```

Tambien tienes un error de logica

```
DESACTIVATE=quit_desactivate(PRODUCT_NUMBER[0])
if DESACTIVATE == False:
   PRODUCTS.append((PRODUCT_NUMBER[0],PRICE))
```

`DESACTIVATE` no deberia llamarse `active`?

```
active = quit_desactivate(PRODUCT_NUMBER[0])
if active == True:
       PRODUCTS.append((PRODUCT_NUMBER[0],PRICE))
```

Comment: no porque se supone que esa lista son artículos que esta desactivados y quiero ignorarlos de la lista principal, muchas gracias el for era el que me daba problemas,